# Incorrect message being shown

Tags: java

I can't make this program show the message "Number out of range" when the user put a number out of (1 - 6). I tried different ways of code, but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int guess = 0;
    int tries = 3;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random ran = new Random();
    int diceNumber = ran.nextInt(6)+1;
    System.out.println(diceNumber);

    System.out.println("Insert a number between 1 and 6 : you have " + tries + " tries.");
    guess = input.nextInt();

    while((tries >1 && (guess <7 || guess>0))) {
        tries--;
        System.out.println("Incorrect Number, you have " +tries+ " more tries.");
        guess = input.nextInt();

    }if(guess >=7 || guess<=0 && (tries >1)){
        --tries;
        System.out.println("Number out of range, try again; you have " + tries + " more tries.");
        guess = input.nextInt();    

    } if(tries ==0 || guess != diceNumber)  {
        System.out.println("You Lose!!");

    } else if(guess == diceNumber){
        System.out.println("You Win!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Check you while loop and conditions to check.

Comment: @Paulo, you can check my answer for the solution may be select it correct if it is working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to position the condition to check if the input is a valid input or not at the start of the while loop , currently, it will only be checked after all tries are exhausted as you end the while loop before it.

Also, you should change the while loop condition from `(tries >1 && (guess <7 || guess>0))` to `(tries > 1 && guess != diceNumber)` , since you may not want to exit the loop if the number entered is outside the range.

Code -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int guess = 0;
    int tries = 3;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random ran = new Random();
    int diceNumber = ran.nextInt(6)+1;
    System.out.println(diceNumber);

System.out.println("Insert a number between 1 and 6 : you have " + tries + " tries.");
guess = input.nextInt();


while((tries >1 && guess != diceNumber)) {
    if((guess >=7 || guess<=0) && (tries >1)){
        --tries;
        System.out.println("Number out of range, try again; you have " + tries + " more tries.");
        guess = input.nextInt();
    }
    else {
        tries--;
        System.out.println("Incorrect Number, you have " +tries+ " more tries.");
        guess = input.nextInt();
    }

}

if(tries ==0 || guess != diceNumber)  {
    System.out.println("You Lose!!");

} else if(guess == diceNumber){
    System.out.println("You Win!!");
}

}
```

Comment: Oh sorry, missed removing an unwanted bracket when copying OP's code, fixed, thank you.

Comment: It still seems to be wrong bro. The logic seems wrong.

Comment: For Example , see the output from your code . 2
Insert a number between 1 and 6 : you have 3 tries.
9
Number out of range, try again; you have 2 more tries.
9
Number out of range, try again; you have 1 more tries.
9
Number out of range, try again; you have 0 more tries.
9
You Lose!!........ Says you have zero tries but still accepts input.

Comment: Sorry to push you, but wrong again !. See the below output and try the same  .............1
Insert a number between 1 and 6 : you have 3 tries.
8
Number out of range, try again; you have 2 more tries.
8
Number out of range, try again; you have 1 more tries.
1
You Lose!!

Comment: Thank you Anand for your help. I have chose your code cause it seems shorter to reach the goal, but all codes here worked like a charm :).

Answer (score 0):

The below code will fetch you the expected result.

```
   import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int guess = 0;
        int tries = 3;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random ran = new Random();
        int diceNumber = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;
        System.out.println(diceNumber);

        System.out.println("Insert a number between 1 and 6 : you have "
                + tries + " tries.");
        guess = input.nextInt();

        loop: while ((tries >= 1)) {
            --tries;
            if ((guess >= 7 || guess <= 0) && (tries >= 1)) {

                System.out.println("Number out of range, try again; you have "
                        + tries + " more tries.");
                guess = input.nextInt();
            } else {

                if (guess == diceNumber) {
                    System.out.println("You Win!!");
                    break loop;
                } else if (tries >= 1) {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect Number, you have " + tries
                            + " more tries.");
                    guess = input.nextInt();

                }
            }
        }

        if (tries == 0 && guess != diceNumber) {
            System.out.println("You Lose!!");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `while` loop.

I'd say it should be something like this:

```
while(tries > 0 && guess != diceNumber) {
    tries--;
    if (guess >= 1 && guess <= 6) {
        System.out.println("Incorrect Number, you have " +tries+ " more tries.");
    } else if (guess >=7 || guess<=0) {
        System.out.println("Number out of range, try again; you have " + tries + " more tries.");
    }
    if (tries > 0) {
        guess = input.nextInt();
    }
}

if(tries == 0 || guess != diceNumber)  {
    System.out.println("You Lose!!");

} else if(guess == diceNumber){
    System.out.println("You Win!!");
}
```

I think this should do what you want.

As you can see, I changed the while condition:

- You want the user to be able to enter another number while he has at least 1 try left, so `tries>0`.
- You want the user to enter another number only if `guess != diceNumber`.

The `if` conditions inside also change:

- You only say it's an incorrect number if the entered number is between 1 and 6: `guess >= 1 && guess <= 6`.
- You only say it's out of range if the number is not between 1 and 6: `guess >= 7 || guess <= 0`.
- You don't need to check the number of tries, the while loop does that already.
- You only want to get a new input number if the user as a try left: `tries > 0`.